Cellspace alternative to ltablex?
I've successfully used the cellspace package to create padding for my graphicsx elements so they don't interfere with the horizontal lines from above, but extrapolating to use with ltablex doesn't work. What kind of alternative do I have for this?
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\centering
\middlexcolumn
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{|X|S{X}|S{X}|} \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Varijabla} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Histogram} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Boxplot} \\ \hline
    \texttt{\scriptsize Monthly\_Inhand\_Salary} & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/Monthly_Inhand_Salary_histogram.png} & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/Monthly_Inhand_Salary_boxplot.png} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|p{0.87\textwidth}|}{
      Comments go here.
    }                                                                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup
\end{document}



X columns like p columns are vertical mode so if you don't want the image at the to use \vspace{...} before the graphic

I'd like to suggest that you replace the aging ltablex machinery with that of the newer xltabular package.
I'd further suggest that you (a) get rid of all vertical rules to give the table a more open and inviting "look" and (b) employ the user macros of the booktabs package -- e.g., \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule -- instead of \hline in order to create well-spaced horizontal rules. That way, there's much much less of a need to employ the cellspace package.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{iftex} \ifpdftex\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\fi
\usepackage[croatian]{babel} % ?
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{xltabular}{0.9\textwidth}{@{} XXX @{}} 

    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Varijabla} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Histogram} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{Boxplot} \\ 
    \midrule

    \texttt{\scriptsize Monthly\_Inhand\_Salary} & 
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image} & 
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image} \\ 
    \midrule % better still: '\addlinespace'
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}p{0.9\textwidth}@{}}{Comments go here.} \\

    \bottomrule

\end{xltabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}


Instead of aging ltablex I would rather use newer longtblr of tabularray package (in the case if your table really need to span several pages). With it code for your table is simpler and a bit shorter:
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}   

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{longtblr}[
    entry=none,     
    label=none      ]{width=0.9\textwidth,
                      colspec = {@{} XXX @{}},
                      row{1}  = {c}
                     }
    \toprule
Varijabla   &   Histogram   &   Boxplot                           \\
    \midrule
\texttt{\scriptsize Monthly\_Inhand\_Salary} 
            &   \includegraphics{example-image-a} 
                            &   \includegraphics{example-image-b} \\
    \midrule 
\SetCell[c=3]{}   Comments go here.
            &               &                                    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\endgroup

\end{document} 



+1 :-). I suppose the main code streamlining success, relative to the code I use in my answer, comes from the instruction \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}, which makes specifying the option width=\linewidth in the subsequent\includegraphics directives unnecessary. But this simplification is due to a good use of the machinery of the graphicx package, rather than that of the tabularray package, right? Or am I missing something?

@Mico, you are right. Gin is related to graphic (first +1 to your nice answer was mine :-) )
